# Catch "Internal Server Errror" when database does not exist with Flask and SQLALchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a web application which uses Flask and SQLAlchemy on MySQL running on Google AppEngine ( i.e. gunicorn ).

My error handler looks like this:

```
@main.app_errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_error(e):
     # ...some other code to interpret different errors...
     return render_template("some_pretty_template.html")
```

The error handler works well for most errors, but database-level errors ( for clarity, query-level errors are fine ) are not caught and you see a nasty "Internal Server Error" plaintext message. For example, dropping the database triggers the nasty error.

How do I create a catchall for "database gone" errors ( and any other errors aside from a complete Flask failure )?

Comment: It can't function without the database, but an abrupt technical message is not helpful to customers trying to use the website. We would prefer to return a prettier custom error page which retains our branding and pushes users to our telephone line to avoid losing business.

Comment: Wrapping the call to `db.create_all` (if there is one) in a try/except may help; also any other attempts to access `db.*` outside of a request.  Done well, that might defer exceptions until a request handler tries to access the database, and then the error handle should kick in.